# Telephon library python

Tags: python

such a problem I use the telephon library in python, I have several different accounts, when I use, for example, a Croatian number, everything is fine for me, but when I want to use Russian, this account crashes from these devices and ends the session accordingly telephon

I thought that the problem is purely in me, for example telegram blocks ip, but another person tried the code and he has the same problem
I have an authorization window that looks like this, on Croatian numbers it runs normally without any errors, on Russian numbers it sometimes gives this error (sometimes everything happens fine)

```
Returned when all available options for this type of number were already used (e.g. flash-call, then SMS, then this error might be returned to trigger a second resend) (caused by ResendCodeRequest)
```

After this error occurs, I still get the telegram code, I drive it in and then after a while I am thrown out of all devices from this account

My code:

```
class LoginWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LoginWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Login")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 200)

        layout = QFormLayout()

        self.api_id_input = QLineEdit()
        self.api_hash_input = QLineEdit()
        self.phone_number_input = QLineEdit()
        self.code_input = QLineEdit()

        layout.addRow("API ID", self.api_id_input)
        layout.addRow("API Hash", self.api_hash_input)
        layout.addRow("Phone Number", self.phone_number_input)
        layout.addRow("Code", self.code_input)

        self.login_button = QPushButton("Login")
        self.login_button.clicked.connect(self.login)

        layout.addRow(self.login_button)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def login(self):
        try:
            api_id = self.api_id_input.text()
            api_hash = self.api_hash_input.text()
            phone_number = self.phone_number_input.text()
            input_code = self.code_input.text()
            self.client = TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash)

            self.client.connect()
            if not self.client.is_user_authorized():
                self.client.send_code_request(phone_number)

            try:
                self.client.sign_in(phone_number, input_code)
                self.accept()
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
        except Exception as e:
                print(e)
```

Comment: @rochard4u How to fix this problem with Russian numbers, i need to use them

Comment: Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)